# selecting all text within a div on a single left click with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple non-clickable link within a div that looks like this:
[image]

It's meant to be a sharable link that the user can copy paste into other things.

For usability purposes, I want a single left click anywhere within the div to select the entire link:
[image]

I don't know much about, javascript/web programming, so I've tried the following:

```
<div id="share_link" onClick="select_all('share_link')"><%= request.url %></div>
```

and this javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function select_all(id) {
        document.getElementById(id).focus();
    }
</script>
```

This doesn't work. I'd like to know what's the simplest thing I should do to achieve what I want. I thought about changing the div to a text input or the text within to be a link, but ideally the content within should be read-only, non-editable, and non-clickable

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/jquery-selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse

Answer (score 18):

This is achieved completely differently in IE compared to other browsers. The following will work in all major browsers:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function select_all(el) {
        if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined" && typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
            var range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNodeContents(el);
            var sel = window.getSelection();
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" && typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
            var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
            textRange.moveToElementText(el);
            textRange.select();
        }
    }
</script>

<div onclick="select_all(this)">Link text</div>
```

Comment: I tested this and it seems to work. But I ended up going with Sime's answer below for readability and compactness. Thank you.

Comment: Fair enough, Šime's is probably the best solution.

Comment: I'm voting for yours Tim because it best fits the question which was to select text within a div, not an input with read only status. Thank you for the good answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can use jQuery for this with an input field:

```
$("#myInputField").focus(function(){
    // Select input field contents
    this.select();
});
```

You can mask the fact that it is an input field using the readonly attribute in the html:

```
    <input type="text" name="country" value="Norway"
  readonly="readonly" />
```

And use CSS to change the cursor so it won't hint a text input, something like:

```
cursor: crosshair;
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The problem is that you bind the focus event. As a result (for some reason) the selection does not persist. Binding the click event, however, does work.