# ReactJS & Material-UI: How to highlight just content inside Material-UI's <Dialog> and not the whole page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, material-ui

In my ReactJS project, I'm using `<Dialog>` (http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dialog), and when I open up the `<Dialog>` and press command + a on Mac, it highlights the whole page rather than just the content in the `<Dialog>`.

How can I highlight just the content inside `<Dialog>` while the `<Dialog>` is open by pressing command + a on Mac?

Thank you in advance and will accept/upvote the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be done. You'll need to listen for Command-A (or Ctrl-A on Windows) on `window.document` in `componentDidMount()` and perform the text selection programmatically. For cleanup, you un-listen in `componentWillUnmount()`.

Working example here: http://www.webpackbin.com/41BuFVuBz

```
import React from 'react';
import { Dialog } from 'material-ui';

class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // In ES6 classes, class methods like handleKeyDown aren't automatically bound to "this"
    this.handleKeyDown = this.handleKeyDown.bind(this);
  }

  handleKeyDown(e) {
    // If the A key is pressed while CTRL or COMMAND are also being pressed
    if (e.key === 'a' && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) {
      // Don't perform the default action, which would select everything on page
      e.preventDefault();

      const win = window;
      const doc = win.document;
      // this.dialogBody is the div's DOM element captured in the ref={}
      const element = this.dialogBody;

      if (doc.body.createTextRange) {      // check if this is Internet Explorer
        // Select all text in "element", the IE way
        var range = doc.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(element);
        range.select();
      } else if (win.getSelection) {      // other browsers...
        // Select all text in "element", the standard way
        var selection = win.getSelection();
        var range = doc.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(element);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
      }     
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Element has been rendered, start capturing keyboard activity
    window.document.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyDown);
  }

  componnetWillUnmount() {
    // Element is no longer been rendered, stop listening
    window.document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyDown);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          Some text I don't want selected.
        </p>
        <p>
          More text I don't want selected.
        </p>
        <Dialog open>
          // Capture a reference to the div's DOM element inside ref={...} as this.dialogBody
          <div ref={(ref) => (this.dialogBody = ref)}>
            <h1>Hello World!</h1>
            <p>Nice day, isn't it?</p>
          </div>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default HelloWorld;
```

The code that actually performs the selection of text confined to a DOM element can be seen in slight variations in other answers on SO:

[Select all DIV text with single mouse click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173194/select-all-div-text-with-single-mouse-click)

[selecting all text within a div on a single left click with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578398/selecting-all-text-within-a-div-on-a-single-left-click-with-javascript)

[Select all or highlight all Text in an Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21147949/select-all-or-highlight-all-text-in-an-element)

...the only additional 'trick' is knowing where to put DOM manipulation code like this within the React component lifecycle (primarily `componentDidMount`, usually with the help of a `ref`, and sometimes cleanup is necessary in `componentWillUnmount`)

Comment: Thank you! It worked beautifully but I'm trying to learn as well. Before I accept the answer and upvote, do you mind briefly commenting as to how each line is working? Thank you!

Comment: Sure! I just added comments. Hope that helps!